# Verify UserName and Password in Spring MVC hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have this code of hibernateTemplate to verify the username and password but this code was working fine with MYSQL but failed in Oracle and was showing some problem in DAO class as it created the table but not saving the value.For project it was necessary to use Oracle

```
package com.infotech.dao.impl;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
    import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.infotech.dao.StudentDAO;
    import com.infotech.model.Student;

    @Repository("studentDAO")
    public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

        @Autowired
        private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

        public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
            this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
        }
        public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
            return hibernateTemplate;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean saveStudent(Student student) {
            int id = (Integer)hibernateTemplate.save(student);
            if(id>0)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Student getStudentDetailsByEmailAndPassword(String email,String password){
            DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria =  DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class);
            detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
            detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));
            List<Student> findByCriteria = (List<Student>) hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
            if(findByCriteria !=null && findByCriteria.size()>0)
            return findByCriteria.get(0);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

**Now I again changed the DAO class instead of HibernateTemplate I used Session Interface and now value are saving in Database but the Validation of username and password is not taking place some issues in Hibernate Template.Please suggest changes instead of hibernate template what should I use

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.infotech.dao.StudentCredentialDao;
import com.infotech.model.Student;
import com.infotech.model.StudentCredential;

@Repository("StudentCredentialDAO")
public class StudentCredentialDaoImpl implements StudentCredentialDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;


    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveStudentCred(StudentCredential stuCred) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(stuCred);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
         return true;
    }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override//This method is creating problem as I need to use something else other than Hibernate Template 
        public StudentCredential getStudentDetailsByUnameAndPassword(String uname,String password){
            DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria =  DetachedCriteria.forClass(StudentCredential.class);
            detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("uname", uname));
            detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));
            List<StudentCredential> findByCriteria = (List<StudentCredential>)hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
            if(findByCriteria !=null && Hibernate template .size()>0)
            return findByCriteria.get(0);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *but failed in Oracle and was showing some problem in DAO class as it created the table*. What was the error? Have you changed the Hibernate dialect to Oracle?

Comment: Yes everything I changed all the Database Property

Comment: @AlanHay not showing any error but Query not triggered  to insert into database but the table is created

Answer (score 1):

```
@Repository
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public String loginCheck(String customerID, String password) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from UserAccount u where u.customerID=:id AND u.password=:pass");
        theQuery.setParameter("id", customerID);
        theQuery.setParameter("pass", password);

        List results = theQuery.list();

        if ((results!=null) && (results.size()>0)){
            return "success";
        }
        else {
        return "failed";
    }

}
```

You could use in this way

Comment: BUt this returning to the Jsp page we need to return to the object of Student Credential